# hide Navbar before login page in angular5

Tags: navigation, angular5, angular4-router

i'm working in angular5 app , so i've used an angular5 template in github , and i tried to do the same as this tutorial to hide the navigation bar before authentication https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-hide-navbar-login-page/

I don't get any errors but the nav bar is always hidden even after the authentication of Users .. , i'm working with backend spring boot (spring security + JWT )

this is how the project structure looks like :

[image]

The file app-sidebar-component.html  :

**in this file i get a red line under the "isLoggedIn$" it says : ng identifier isloggedIn$ is not defined , the component declaration , template variable declaration and elements references do not contain such a member**

```
 <div class="sidebar">
  <app-sidebar-header></app-sidebar-header>
  <app-sidebar-form></app-sidebar-form>
  <app-sidebar-nav *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async"></app-sidebar-nav>
  <app-sidebar-footer></app-sidebar-footer>
  <app-sidebar-minimizer></app-sidebar-minimizer>
</div>
```

As you see i'm using a condition ngIf to test if the variable isLoggedIn$ is true , if it's true the nav bar will show up .

the file app-sidebar-nav.component.ts that uses the file _nav.ts

```
   import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../../../service/authentication.service';

// Import navigation elements
import { navigation } from './../../_nav';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-nav',
  template: `
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <ng-template ngFor let-navitem [ngForOf]="navigation">
          <li *ngIf="isDivider(navitem)" class="nav-divider"></li>
          <ng-template [ngIf]="isTitle(navitem)">
            <app-sidebar-nav-title [title]='navitem'></app-sidebar-nav-title>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template [ngIf]="!isDivider(navitem)&&!isTitle(navitem)">
            <app-sidebar-nav-item [item]='navitem'></app-sidebar-nav-item>
          </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
      </ul>
    </nav>`
})
export class AppSidebarNavComponent implements OnInit {

  public navigation = navigation ;

  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private authService:AuthenticationService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
  }


  public isDivider(item) {
    return item.divider ? true : false
  }

  public isTitle(item) {
    return item.title ? true : false
  }



}
```

in src/app/views/pages/login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../../../service/authentication.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  mode:number=0;

  constructor(private router:Router , private authService:AuthenticationService) { }


  onLogin(user){
    this.authService.login(user)
      .subscribe(resp=>{
          let jwt = resp.headers.get('Authorization');
           this.authService.saveToken(jwt);
           this.authService.setLoggedInt();
           this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');

        },
        err=>{
          this.mode=1;
        })
  }

}
```

In directory service :

File : auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {AuthenticationService} from './authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn
      .take(1)
      .map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn){
          this.router.navigate(['pages']);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
  }
}
```

The file authentication.service.ts :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {JwtHelper} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService{

  private host:string="http://localhost:8080";
  private jwtToken=null ;
  private roles:Array<any>;
  private user:string;
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.tokenAvailable());

  get isLoggedIn(){
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  private tokenAvailable(): boolean {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  constructor(private http:HttpClient){

  }
  login(user){

    return this.http.post(this.host+"/login",user,{observe: 'response'});

  }

  getToken(){
    return this.jwtToken;
  }

  setLoggedInt(){
    this.loggedIn.next(true);

  }

  loadToken(){
    this.jwtToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
```

The file app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Import Containers
import {
  FullLayoutComponent,
  SimpleLayoutComponent
} from './containers';
import {AuthGuard} from '../service/auth.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'pages',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'GestionClients',
        loadChildren: './views/Admin/GestionClients/client.module#ClientModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'GestionDevloppeurs',
        loadChildren: './views/Admin/GestionDevloppeurs/devloppeur.module#DevloppeurModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'GestionProject',
        loadChildren: './views/Admin/GestionProjects/projet.module#ProjetModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: './views/base/base.module#BaseModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'buttons',
        loadChildren: './views/buttons/buttons.module#ButtonsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: './views/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'icons',
        loadChildren: './views/icons/icons.module#IconsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: './views/notifications/notifications.module#NotificationsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'theme',
        loadChildren: './views/theme/theme.module#ThemeModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'widgets',
        loadChildren: './views/widgets/widgets.module#WidgetsModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'pages',
    component: SimpleLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Pages'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './views/pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

As you can see i've added as in the tutorial the value  canActivate: [AuthGuard] for the path: 'dashboard',

and this is the file _nav.ts that should be hidden before login , and it's the one included in app-sidebar-nav.component.ts above.

```
export const navigation = [
  {
    name: 'Tableau de bord',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
  },
  {
    name: 'Clients',
    url: '/GestionClients',
    icon: 'icon-puzzle',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Liste des clients',
        url: '/GestionClients/list',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ajouter un client',
        url: '/GestionClients/ajouter',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Développeurs',
    url: '/GestionDevloppeurs',
    icon: 'icon-puzzle',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Liste des développeurs',
        url: '/GestionDevloppeurs/list',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ajouter un nouveau développeur',
        url: '/GestionDevloppeurs/ajouter',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Projets',
    url: '/GestionProject',
    icon: 'icon-puzzle',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Liste des projets',
        url: '/GestionProject/list',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ajouter un projet',
        url: '/GestionProject/ajouter',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Base',
    url: '/base',
    icon: 'icon-puzzle',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Cards',
        url: '/base/cards',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Carousels',
        url: '/base/carousels',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Collapses',
        url: '/base/collapses',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Forms',
        url: '/base/forms',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Pagination',
        url: '/base/paginations',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Popovers',
        url: '/base/popovers',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Progress',
        url: '/base/progress',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Switches',
        url: '/base/switches',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tables',
        url: '/base/tables',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tabs',
        url: '/base/tabs',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tooltips',
        url: '/base/tooltips',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Buttons',
    url: '/buttons',
    icon: 'icon-cursor',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Buttons',
        url: '/buttons/buttons',
        icon: 'icon-cursor'
      },
      {
        name: 'Dropdowns',
        url: '/buttons/dropdowns',
        icon: 'icon-cursor'
      },
      {
        name: 'Social Buttons',
        url: '/buttons/social-buttons',
        icon: 'icon-cursor'
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    name: 'Icons',
    url: '/icons',
    icon: 'icon-star',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Flags',
        url: '/icons/flags',
        icon: 'icon-star',
        badge: {
          variant: 'success',
          text: 'NEW'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Font Awesome',
        url: '/icons/font-awesome',
        icon: 'icon-star',
        badge: {
          variant: 'secondary',
          text: '4.7'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Simple Line Icons',
        url: '/icons/simple-line-icons',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Notifications',
    url: '/notifications',
    icon: 'icon-bell',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Alerts',
        url: '/notifications/alerts',
        icon: 'icon-bell'
      },
      {
        name: 'Modals',
        url: '/notifications/modals',
        icon: 'icon-bell'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Widgets',
    url: '/widgets',
    icon: 'icon-calculator',
    badge: {
      variant: 'info',
      text: 'NEW'
    }
  },
  {
    divider: true
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Extras',
  },
  {
    name: 'Pages',
    url: '/pages',
    icon: 'icon-star',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Login',
        url: '/pages/login',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Register',
        url: '/pages/register',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Error 404',
        url: '/pages/404',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Error 500',
        url: '/pages/500',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

when i check the value of isLoggedIn$ after authentication i get 'true' but the nav bar of the file _nav.ts is always hidden . Any idea?

**EDIT**

File : appSidebar.component.ts : this file is empty , because the man who devlopped this template has used the file app-sidebar-nav.component.ts instead of appSidebar.component.ts to show the navigation bar , that's why i declared the variable îsLoggedIn$ in app-sidebar-nav.component.ts as it's in the code .
but i get like a warning : it says :

**in this file i get a red line under the "isLoggedIn$" it says : ng identifier isloggedIn$ is not defined , the component declaration , template variable declaration and elements references do not contain such a member**

[image]

Comment: I don't see you code for the `app-sidebar-component.ts` which defines the `isLoggedIn$` (you have provided the `app-sidebar-nav.component.ts` file but that is the component used by the `app-sidebar-component`)

Comment: Based on your update, I'm pretty sure I was along the right lines. You have defined the `isLoggedIn$` in the wrong component (`app-sidebar-component` should have it... `app-sidebar-nav.component` should not have it).

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel : thank you for your answer , i've edited the post right now , and explained why i used this variable in app-sidebar-nav.component take a look please , and the reason why i want to hide the navigation bar , is that i have 2 different users , so i need two navigation bar , i didn't have choice so i decided to hide the nav bar , if everything goes well , then i will add condition on AuthenticationService to know who is authenticaed and which nav bar  he should see etc.

Comment: You can't define `isLoggedIn$` the way you have. You are trying to use a variable from a different component. I'm not sure how to make it any more clear. You either need to define it in the correct class or remove its use from the incorrect component and move it to the template of the class where it is defined.

Comment: You are incorrect in your understanding of how Angular templates work.

Comment: ah i see , so now i understand why i get this warning ,so give me 5mins i'll try changing this as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either define the `isLoggedIn$` variable in the component that you are currently trying to use it in (`app-sidebar-component.ts`) or you can move the `*ngIf` to the component where you have it defined (`app-sidebar-nav.component.ts`) like so:

`app-sidebar-component.html`

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <app-sidebar-header></app-sidebar-header>
  <app-sidebar-form></app-sidebar-form>
  <app-sidebar-nav></app-sidebar-nav>
  <app-sidebar-footer></app-sidebar-footer>
  <app-sidebar-minimizer></app-sidebar-minimizer>
</div>
```

`app-sidebar-nav.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-nav',
  template: `
    <nav class="sidebar-nav" *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async">
        ...
    </nav>`
})
export class AppSidebarNavComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh Man thank you so much for your help , both methods worked well for me , i really appreciate you help !!